# JavaScript fetch API does not work beginner question

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a simple code, I am trying to sent a post but something is wrong with my code. Post does not work, behind curtains, I have a simple back-end and it works on 100%. So the problem is with code above.
Please help me, maybe something is wrong with the scope?

```
Api = function() {
  this.header = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

Api.prototype.buildUrl = function(id) {
  return "http://localhost:3000/db/shop_name/" + id;
};

Api.prototype.post = function(id, data) {

  const urlPost = api.buildUrl(id.value);
  return fetch(urlPost, {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: this.header
    
   .then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)))
};

Api.prototype.get = function(id) {
  //const urlGet = api.buildUrl(id);
  return fetch(id, {
      method: "GET",
    })
    .then(resp => {
      alert(resp.json());

      return resp.json();
    })
};
Api.prototype.getAlll = function() {
  return fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(resp => {
      alert(resp.json());
      return resp.json()
    })
};

Api.prototype.update = function(id, data) {
  const url = api.buildUrl(id);
  return fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(resp => {
      return resp.json()
        .catch(error => {
          let notFound = "The server can not find requested resource";
          document.getElementById("stars").innerHTML = notFound + error.status;
        })
    })
};


Api.prototype.addProduct = function(id, data) {
  return this.post(id, data);
};

Api.prototype.deleteProduct = function(id) {
  return this.delete(id);
};

Api.prototype.updateProduct = function(id, data) {
  return this.update(id, data);
};

Api.prototype.getProduct = function(id) {
  return this.get(id);
};
Api.prototype.getAllProducts = function() {
  return this.getAlll;
};

const Main = function() {
  this.id = document.getElementById("id");
  this.addCount = document.getElementById("count");
  this.addName = document.getElementById("name");
  this.addPrice = document.getElementById("price");
};


Main.prototype.add = function() {
  // const ido = this.id.value;
  const data = {
    "price": this.addPrice.value,
    "name": this.addName.value,
    "count": this.addCount.value,
  };
  //  let id = api.buildUrl(this.id.value);
  api.addProduct(this.id, data);
};


Main.prototype.update = function() {
  const data = {
    "price": this.price,
    "name": this.name,
    "count": this.count,
  };
  api.updateProduct(id, data);
};

Main.prototype.delete = function() {
  let id = api.buildUrl(this.id);
  api.deleteProduct(id);

};


Main.prototype.get = function() {
  let id = api.buildUrl(this.id.value);
  api.getProduct(id);

};

Main.prototype.getAll = function() {
  api.getAllProducts();

};

const api = new Api();
const main = new Main();


let addButton = document.getElementById('postBtn');
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  main.add();
});

/*
addButton.addEventListener("click",main.add.bind(main));
*/


let updateButton = document.getElementById("updateBtn");
updateButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  main.update();
});


let deleteButton = document.getElementById("deleteBtn");
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  main.delete();
});

let getButton = document.getElementById("getBtn");
getButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  main.get();
});


let getAllButton = document.getElementById("getAllBtn");
getAllButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let tst = main.getAll();
  console.log(tst);

});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and doesn't work? Which method are you calling and what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Post function .

Comment: Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: Hi thank You for help. I have changed code,based on yours instructions but still does not work ...

Comment: Have a look at my edit below. Make sure to go back to your code and fix your issues everywhere where they are present.

Comment: Are you still having issues with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a minimal working example that only deals with your `post` method and I think the issue is with the way you're "building" a URL for the post request:

```js
Api.prototype.post = function(id, data) {
  // WRONG!
  // const urlPost = api.buildUrl(id)

  // CORRECT!
  const urlPost = this.buildUrl(id)

  return fetch(...)
}
```

Have a look at this example which has a similar structure to your code:

```js
const Api = function() {
  this.headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}
Api.prototype.buildUrl = function(id) {
  return `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`
};
Api.prototype.post = function(id, data) {
  const urlPost = this.buildUrl()

  return fetch(urlPost, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    }),
    headers: this.headers,
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
};


function main() {
  const API = new Api()
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById(`submitBtn`)
  
  submitBtn.addEventListener(`click`, function() {
    API.post()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(`data was submitted`, Date.now())
        console.log(`result`, result)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(`handle your errors!`)
      })
  })
}

main()
```

```html
<button id="submitBtn" type="button">Click to submit data</button>
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT**

You have to fix this issue everywhere else, not just the `post` method.

First, you can't access `api` inside of your `Api.prototype.post` method, it is out of scope since you're using `const`, so use `this` when you're trying to call methods on an instance of your object:

```js
const Api = function() { ... }
Api.prototype.buildUrl = function() { ... }
Api.prototype.post = function(id, data) {
  const urlPost = this.buildUrl()
  // ...  
}

const api = new Api()
api.post(...)
```

Second, **always handle your errors and make sure you `catch` promises that fail**. You are most likely unable to debug this problem because you're missing out on errors that would give you clues as to what is happening.

```js
Api.prototype.post = function(id, data) {
  const urlPost = this.buildUrl()

  return fetch(urlPost, {...})
    .then(...)
    .catch(error => { console.log(`error`, error.message) }
}
```

Third, again,  you're running into an issue with scope - `api` is not available in methods of your `Api` and `Main` instances:

```js
Api.prototype.post = function(...) {
  api.buildUrl(...) // NOT IN SCOPE!
}
Main.prototype.getAll = function() {
  api.getAllProducts() // ALSO NOT IN SCOPE
}
```

Do this instead:

```js
const Main = function(api) {
  this.api = api
  // ...
}
Main.prototype.add = function() {
  const data = {...}
  return this.api.addProduct(this.id, data)
}

const api = new Api()
const main = new Main(api) // PASS `api` TO A CONSTRUCTOR
const btn = document.getElementById(`button`)

btn.addEventListener(`click`, function() {
  main.add()
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
})
```

**Go back and fix your all your methods inside of `Api` and `Main`!**

Here's a working example:

```js
const Api = function() {
  this.headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}
Api.prototype.buildUrl = function(id) {
  return `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`
};
Api.prototype.post = function(id, data) {
  const urlPost = this.buildUrl()

  return fetch(urlPost, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    }),
    headers: this.headers,
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
};
Api.prototype.addProduct = function(id, data) {
  return this.post(id, data)
}

function Main(api) {
  this.api = api
  this.id = 1
}
Main.prototype.add = function() {
  const data = {
    "price": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "count": 20
  }
  return this.api.addProduct(this.id, data)
}

const api = new Api()
const main = new Main(api)
const submitBtn = document.getElementById(`submitBtn`)

submitBtn.addEventListener(`click`, function() {
  main.add()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`data was submitted`, Date.now())
      console.log(`result`, result)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(`handle your errors!`)
    })
})
```

```html
<button id="submitBtn" type="button">Click me!</button>
```